# If Hawking's last paper is correct, is it valid to assume that we live in a 5 dimensional universe?

Tags: universe, spacetime-dimensions, multiverse

If I understand Hawking's last paper, ["A smooth exit from eternal inflation?"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.07702) (2018-04-27), correctly it implies that the Big Bang generated more universes than our own.

This means that to locate a point in all of the universes we would need a 5-D Coordinate system $\left(x,y,z,t,u\right)$.

Also, if that is the case, do we need to create a new word to describe all the universes as a whole?

Comment: what like the multi-verse?

Comment: Added a link to what appears to have been regarded as Hawking's last paper.  Assuming that it's the right one, could you quote the section of it that you took to imply a 5-dimensional universe?

Comment: The query about new terminologywould be off topic, though I think it'd be best if you described what you mean by the coordinate $u$.

Comment: Opps - misread your question the first time!  Okay, so Hawking didn't suggest a 5-dimensional universe, but rather that's your proposed solution to create a system for identifying locations across an ensemble of divergent spaces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***tl;dr*-**  There's no need to preemptively standardize terms and notation.  Individual authors will choose their own terms and notation as appropriate, and standards can emerge when individual authors consistently find the same terms and notation to be optimal.

---

> Also, if that is the case, do we need to create a new word to describe all the universes as a whole?

This may sound weird, but we never really plan to standardize terms like this.  The process is far more organic than that.

Writers write things to be easier on readers.  This usually means using existing words whenever possible because asking readers to learn new definitions is placing a burden on them.

The burden of new terms can be worthwhile in unusual cases, e.g.:

- There's not an existing word already that fits.
- Two closely related concepts that would normally be referred to with the same word need to be distinguished from each other.
- Existing terms are intrinsically undesirable, e.g. they're really wordy for a term that'll be used frequently.

When standard definitions do emerge, it's because writers consistently find that using the standard definition is of greater benefit to readers than creating new words.

Here I won't use the word "*multiverse*"; I don't see it as beneficial.  If anyone else answers, they might, or someone in some other context may, as they see fit.  If I end up writing something else about this later, and in that time "*multiverse*" has become the widely accepted term for this exact concept, then I'd probably find it as beneficial in that context.  But, again, I don't find it worthwhile now.

---

> This means that to locate a point in all of the universes we would need a 5-D Coordinate system $\left(x,y,z,t,u\right)$.

I get where you're coming from: extend $\left(x,y,z,t\right)$ with a new discriminant, $u$, to identify the corresponding universe.  This isn't really "*wrong*", though I'd find it to be suboptimal.

The biggest issue is that, at current, I don't see any reason to write about coordinates across a hypothetical set of universes; so, just like there's no point in defining terms for their own sake, there's no point in defining syntax for its own sake.

However, say that someone does wish to write about coordinates across a hypothetical set of universes.  My next critique would be that the universe-discriminant, $u$, is given about as much priority as the other coordinates and has the appearance of being a scalar.

Instead, I'd probably prefer something like $\left(x,y,z,t\right)_u$; having an indexer in a subscript is more standard ([principle of least surprise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment)).  This more clearly conveys that it's an indexer as opposed to a scalar, and it makes it easier for writers to painlessly drop the $u$-discriminant, reverting to $\left(x,y,z,t\right)$, if they switch into the context of a particular universe such that continuously qualifying the value of $u$ becomes redundant.

Ultimately, though, it'll be a matter of how folks who write about this sorta thing choose to express their thoughts, which they'll tend to select in a manner considerate of readers.  Terminology and notation tend to be organic like this.